# Multiple JInternalFrame view

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I create the multiple JInternalFrame. It is working properly. But when create the JInternalFrame, it is load over the existing one. I need the JInternalFrame like as table cells (row by row).

Comment: This will come down to how you are creating the `JInternalFrame`s, but you need to change the size and position based on your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `JInternalFrame`s where you want them placed and at what size.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestInternalFrameLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInternalFrameLayout();
    }

    public TestInternalFrameLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(desktop);
                frame.setSize(420, 420);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int rowCount = 2;
                        int colCount = 4;

                        int width = desktop.getWidth() / colCount;
                        int height = desktop.getHeight() / rowCount;

                        System.out.println(width + "x" + height);

                        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
                            int y = row * height;
                            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
                                int x = col * width;
                                JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame(row + "x" + col, true, true, true, true);
                                frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                desktop.add(frame);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, you've provided absolutely no context to your question, so it's hard to know exactly what it is you need.

If the frames are being added over time, then you need to determine the best place to put them based on your needs.  A common approach is to use a `static` `x` and `y` value, which you increment as required when you add a new frame.

You could write your own "pack" algorithm which will automatically tile the windows as you want thme.

You could simply use a `GridLayout` instead of `JInternalFrame`s....